# free product of two Leibniz algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

I am looking for the definition of free product of two Leibniz algebras.
Is there any reference for this?
Yours,

Comment: Why would the definition be specific to Leibniz algebras?

Comment: A definition would not be specific. A construction would be the quotient of the free product of the underlying non-associative algebras by the Leibniz relations. On the other hand a more explicit description (such as a reasonable direct sum decomposition in terms of specific products- typically a basis when we start with bases) would be specific.